# Preserving all the subdirectories when saving a file - Python

Tags: python, recursion, glob, subdirectory

I have a folder with various subdirectories and within those are files with different extensions such as .jpg, .png, etc. I would like to only extract the .jpg files and perform some work on them such as cropping, etc and then I want to save these *new* files (i.e. cropped ones) into the subdirectories that they came from. However, I don't want these new files saved into the same folder from which they came from. Instead, I want them saved into a different folder that contains all of the same subdirectories with the same names from which they came from. This new folder must only contain the *new* cropped files. I have included an illustration below to better explain my question.
[image]

I have tried the following:

```
for imgs in glob.iglob(self.Main_Folder + '//**/*.jpg', recursive=True):
    Output_Folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(imgs), "cropped" + str(idx) + ".jpg")
```

However, this overwrites the .jpg files located in their subdirectories in the Main Folder (i.e. it overwrites 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc). Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where/how are you identifying the main output folder?

Comment: I send the path of it as a Parameter in Pycharm

Comment: How are you using it in your code to create the new files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to realize is that the paths that `glob.iglob` generates include the entire matched pattern, which includes your `self.Main_Folder`.  So, you must first determine the sub-path relative to the main folder, and join that with the output folder.  E.g. `"main_folder/found/path.jpg"` -> `"found/path.jpg"` -> `"output_folder/found/path.jpg"`.  The `pathlib` library provides an easy way to do that with [`Path.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to).

```py
import glob
import os
import pathlib

main_folder = "somewhere/Main Folder"
output_folder = "somewhere/Output Folder"
for name in glob.iglob(os.path.join(main_folder, "**/*")):
    path = pathlib.Path(name)
    sub_path = path.relative_to(main_folder)
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, sub_path)
    print(output_path)
```

You can get fancier by using more of the `pathlib` API (especially the ability to join paths with `/`), but whether this is more clear is probably debatable:

```
main_folder = "somewhere/Main Folder"
output_folder = "somewhere/Output Folder"
for name in glob.iglob(str(main_folder / "**/*")):
    path = pathlib.Path(name)
    output_path = output_folder / path.relative_to(main_folder)
    print(output_path)
```

In Python 3.10, which as of this writing is the newest Python version, this can be simpler:

```py
main_folder = pathlib.Path("scratch")
output_folder = pathlib.Path("output")
for name in glob.iglob("**/*", root_dir=main_folder):
    output_path = output_folder / name
    print(output_path)
```

Comment: I was not aware of the Path.relative_to function. This really helped so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, these are 3 issues

- iglob for finding jpg files
- Pillow for image manipulation
- a mechanism for creating path to new jpg file

First you got already, second is trivial, third like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
apath = Path(“a/b/c/a.jpg”)  # to your jpg
root = “a/b”
new_dir = Path(“some/path”)
new_path = new_dir.joinpath(apath.relative_to(root))
# should be some/path/c/a.jpg
```

No python here, so not tested.